# How i can loop thought for loop and use ajax to show result in django?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-views

I have a question about django and ajax, i want to show result of forloop with ajax. I have code below when i submit button, my html doesn't append data of ajax call. Anyone have solotion about this. Thanks for answer

This is my view

```py
def test_ajax(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for i in range(10):
            helloworld(i)
    return render(request, 'test_ajax.html')

def helloworld(request, i):
    data = {
        'status': i
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

This is my url

```py
   path('testajax/', test_ajax),
   path('helloworld/<int:i>/', helloworld, name='ajaxsend')
```

And this is my html file{% extends 'base.html' %}

```py
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <form id="test" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" id="id_username">
            <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Check Token Live</button>
        </form>
        <div id="people">

        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
{% block script %}
    <script>
        $("#test").on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(e);
            $("#people").html('<h2>Hello World</h2>');
            $.ajax({
                url: "/helloworld/",
                success: function(result){
                    alert('Hello world');
                    console.log(result.status)
                    $("#people").append('<h2>' + result.status + '</h2>');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock script %}
```

Comment: There is no ID in the URL, it should be `url: "/helloworld/{some id}/",` instead of  `url: "/helloworld/",`

Comment: Any ways to put id in thats, i want to use for loop in views :(

Comment: send id as query parameter. ex: `data: {id: 'id to send'}` in ajax